# How to get all rows from a database table?

Tags: database

I have the table where I store uid column. I want to get all the values from that table, but I only get the frist element.

My query:

```
$sql = db_select('voting_nomination_counter', 'v')
->fields('v', array('uid'))
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DatabaseStatementBase::fetchAssoc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementBase%3A%3AfetchAssoc/7) fetches the next row and returns it as an associative array.

```
$query = db_select('voting_nomination_counter', 'v');
$query->fields('v',array('uid'));
$result = $query->execute();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  print_r($record);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

check with this

```
 $query = db_select('voting_nomination_counter','v');
 $query->fields('v');
 $results=$query->execute()->fetchAll();
 print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this for fetching all records. Remove condition if you don't want to add.

```
<?php
    $query = db_select('data');
    $query->fields('data', array('LivingArea', 'Postalcode', 'Street'));
    $query->condition('Postalcode', $postalcode);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetch();
    drupal_set_message($result->street);
    drupal_set_message($result->livingarea);
?>
```